# Pointer to member attribute

Tags: c

I have a function `f(unsigned char ** data);`. Additionally, I have a pointer to an object `pObj`  with an `unsigned char* pbCert` member. Thus I'd like to perform an operation such as this:

```
f(pObj->&pbCert);
```

Unfortunately, I get `member identifier expected` error.

I managed to tackle with the problem using such approach:

```
unsigned char* temp = pObj->pbCert;
f(&temp);
```

However I'm curious, is there some clever notation trick do do this in only one line?

Comment: Why did you not try to replace temp in the function call with the value that you assign to temp ? That would have answered your question immediately and is better what you intend to do. &temp takes the address of temp.

Comment: To be honest, the problem is slightly more complex and I got stuck with casts which then pointed me to wrong problem. However, the answers helped me understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&` goes before the entire member-access expression: `f(&pObj->pbCert)`.

(In fact, your own solution with `unsigned char* temp` is incomplete! Calling `f(&temp)` would modify `temp`, but wouldn't modify `pObj->pbCert`, unless you manually re-assign it with `pObj->pbCert = temp;` after calling `f`.)

Comment: It was not meant to modify pObj attribute, but that's the interface I have to work with. So the solution is all right, but thanks for pointing out the possible hole in logic.

Comment: If you didn't mean to modify `pObj->pbCert`, then why did you try `f(pObj->&pbCert)`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Pass the content of `pbCert` to the function without actually modyfing `pObj`.

Comment: If you don't expect `f` to modify anything, then I'm surprised it takes `const char**` and not `const char *const *`...

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
f(&(pObj->pbCert));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all what do we have here? A pointer to object `pObj`.

---

Ok. Then we want to access the member of an object which is `pbCert`. How do we do that?
To access a member of an object we can use *dot notation* or *arrow notation* (if we have pointer to object).

1. **Dot Notation**
   Dot notation is used to access the member of an class as

   `object.member`  or

   `(*object_pointer).member`

So we can access `pbCert` as `*pObj.pbCert` using *dot notation*.

2. **Arrow Notation**
   Arrow notation is used to access the member of a class as

   `object_pointer->member`

Note we can not use `object_name` with arrow notation to access the member.

So we can access `pbCert` as `pObj->pbCert` using *arrow notation*.

---

Now what do we want to do next? We want to pass the address of this member to function `f()`.

To get the address of a variable we use `&` operator (address of operator). So there we have it.

The address of `pbCert` can be written as:

1. `&((*pObj).pbCert)` (dot notation)
2. `&(pObj->pbCert)` (arrow notation)

Note- It's preferable to use `arrow notation` to access the member whenever we have `object pointer` though we can access the member using `dot notation` too.

---

So the correct way would be:

`f(&((*pObj).pbCert));`  or

`f(&(pObj->pbCert));`